# Qt перенос с Linux в Windows

Tags: qt

> C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\rabotaSeichas\ISPYM-stantion3 (2)\mainwindow.h:11: ошибка: C2504: QMainWindow: не определен базовый класс
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\rabotaSeichas\ISPYM-stantion3 (2)\main.cpp:12: ошибка: C2079: "a" использует неопределенный class "QApplication"
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\rabotaSeichas\ISPYM-stantion3 (2)\main.cpp:12: ошибка: C2078: слишком много инициализаторов

и далее 15 ошибок в том же духе. Программа прекрасно собирается и работает в lunix(убунту), но потом я перенес её на винду, так вот и результат.

Работаю в той же версии Qt, но в винде.

Comment: В общем слегка исправил и стала работать но в moc файле говорит ошибка C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\rabotaSeichas\ISPYM-stantion3 (2)\ui_mainwindow.h:14: ошибка: C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: QtGui/QAction: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

При переносе исходников Qt-проекта между разными (да и одинаковыми тоже) операционными системами не стоит захватывать папку сборки проекта.

При переносе желательно исключить и файл *.pro.user, поскольку последний содержит настройки сборки под конкретные параметры и пути, которые в свою очередь могут оказаться неприемлемы на целевой системе. IDE QtCreator обычно выводит предупреждение в таких ситуациях, однако в иных средах разработки поведение может отличаться.

Не стоит использовать для своих проектов папки, пути к которым содержат символы кириллицы, либо ещё какие-нибудь, что могут в отдельных случаях помешать процессу сборки. Не то чтобы это было прямо-таки безусловное к следованию правило, но имеет смысл, говоря простым языком, во избежание из ниоткуда взявшегося геморроя. Постарайтесь избегать таких или подобных наименований: "ISPYM-stantion3 (2)".

Ну а в качестве решения просто вычистите от всех файлов имеющуюся папку сборки (в том числе и Makefile) и скорректируйте пути в соответствии с рекомендациями для душевного спокойствия. Затем заново соберите проект.